# Read binary FAU format in python

Tags: python, numpy, struct, binary

I am trying to read a binary file, but I am not getting the correct results.
I understood that I must unpack the file every 24 bytes, but I believe that I am wrong.

```
import struct
with open(r'0039_20091018_134924_Wessex_Explorer_TC.fau', 'br') as f:
    buffer = f.read()

    for x in range(len(buffer)-24):
        data = struct.unpack("<iiiihccBBcB", buffer[0+x:24+x])
        print(data)
```

This is the format description:
https://studylib.net/doc/7315604/annex-a---fau-format-description

And this is the file that I am trying to read: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApnRwVlEp51msMALYIODyPODpdAI9A?e=k9HTrW

How can I use struct.unpack to get the correct results?
Thank you kindly for reading, and for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in range(0, len(buffer), 24):
    data = struct.unpack("<iiiihccBBcB", buffer[x:x+24])
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The values no make sense for me.
The first integer value must be a number starting with 5729.

Answer (score 0):

The FAU file may have an initial header. Give a look at the official [FAU Format Specs v1](https://gst.dk/Media/637731723716700972/FAU%20Format%20Specs.v1.20211118.pdf).